# C++ how to make a class function a friend of another class in a different namespace

Tags: c++

My question is in relation to making a function in a class a friend of another class. Both classes are in different namespaces though.

For example the example below does not compile as it says that `namespace o` doesn't exist.

```
namespace m
{
    class Value
    {
        friend std::vector<std::string> m::o::returnList();
    }
}


namespace m
{
    namespace o
    {
     class Operation
     std::vector<std::string> returnList() const;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the namespace before:

```
namespace m
{
    namespace o
    {
    }

    class Value
    {
        friend std::vector<std::string> m::o::returnList();
    }
}
```